# Unable to get r_emailaddress from https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

Tags: linkedin-api

I have used,

```
<OAuthConfig  oAuthScope="r_liteprofile r_emailaddress" providerId="LINKED_IN" userProfileUrl="https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me"/>
```

and using `OAuth2` for this but I'm unable retrieve email with this. Is there possibility to get both email & liteprofile from single `accesstoken` request?

My app is having permissions with

```
r_liteprofile
r_emailaddress
w_member_social
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

THIS IS THE RESPONSE I'm getting,

THIS IS JSON OBJECT:

```
{"lastName":{"localized":{"en_US":"global"},"preferredLocale":{"country":"US","language":"en"}},"firstName":{"localized":{"en_US":"Gifting"},"preferredLocale":{"country":"US","language":"en"}},"id":"_Ru_P5gptv"}

net.sf.json.JSONException: JSONObject["emailAddress"] not found.
```

Answer (score 2):

The email address is available via the /emailAddress API, not the /me API.

You will need to make an additional GET request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/emailAddress?q=members&projection=(elements*(handle~))`